# Best way to append newline to string except for last

Tags: c#, .net, string, refactoring

I was looking for the best/cleanest way to iterate over a list of strings and then create a single string of those separated by newlines (except for the last). Like so:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

I have written two loops here which has a newline at the end of the string (which I want to avoid) and another that does not. The one does not just doesn't seem "clean" to me. I would think there would be a simpler way to do it so that the logic is nearly as simple as in the example that has a new line to the end of the string.

```
List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
string messages = "";

//Adds newline to last string. Unwanted.
foreach(string msg in errorMessages)
{
    messages += msg + "\n";
}

messages = "";
bool first = true;

//Avoids newline on last string
foreach (string msg in errorMessages)
{
    if(first)
    {
        first = false;
        messages = msg;
    }
    else
    {
        messages += "\n" + msg;
    }
}
```

Maybe it is wishful thinking, but I would have thought this was a common enough occurrence to warrant a better way to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

```
string.Join("\n", errorMessages);
```

Comment: Found a similar API on the `Sequence` protocol in Swift! `joined(separator: "\n")`

Answer (score 95):

Use join

```
string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, errorMessages);
```

Answer (score 18):

```
using System;

string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessages);
```

Answer (score 7):

The shortest way is to use either `.Aggregate(...)` or `String.Join(...)`.

```
var messages = errorMessages.Aggregate((x, y) => x + Environment.NewLine + y);
```

Or

```
var messages = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessages);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems using

```
string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, errorMessages);
```

In the page, instead of the new line I was getting **\r\n** instead. I solved it by using

```
string.Join("<br>", errorMessages);
```